# Should I disable all UI modules once the site is in production?

Tags: 7

Just wondering if I should I disable all UI modules once the site is in production?
e.g.: Context UI

Most of them are not required for any other module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably considered best practice in terms of performance because on every call each module is loaded into memory and executed.

However you may find it annoying to have to constantly re-enable the modules, particularly with views or rules.

Comment: I agree. I guess the question is how much the performance is improved by disabling these module... to hang this in the balance.

Comment: To get around having to constantly disable and re-enable modules, use the feature in the admin menu module that allows you to specify which modules to disable with one click. See http://drupal.org/node/944810#comment-3646430 for more info.